# How to find the DataKeyValue from RadTreeList UpdateCommand?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, radtreelist

How on earth do I find the DataKey when I'm doing an update?  I've tried everything...

```
Private Sub rtlAccounts_UpdateCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.TreeListCommandEventArgs) Handles rtlAccounts.UpdateCommand
    Dim txtAccountDescription As RadTextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtAccountDescription"), RadTextBox)
    Dim txtAdminName As RadTextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtAdminName"), RadTextBox)
    Dim txtAdminEmail As RadTextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtAdminEmail"), RadTextBox)
    Dim rcbStatus As RadComboBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rcbStatus"), RadComboBox)
    Dim rntDocRetention As RadNumericTextBox = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rntDocRetention"), RadNumericTextBox)

    Dim item As TreeListEditableItem = TryCast(e.Item, TreeListEditableItem)
    Dim MyDataKeyID As String =  'Now what???
End Sub
```

Also would like to know how to find the ParentDataKeyValue from an InsertCommand and the UpdateCommand as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the DataKeyValue and the ParentDataKeyValue, change your last two lines to the following:

```
Dim editedItem As TreeListEditFormItem = CType(e.Item, TreeListEditFormItem)
Dim dataKeyValue As String = _
    editedItem.ParentItem.GetDataKeyValue("EmployeeID").ToString()
Dim parentDataKeyValue As String = _
    editedItem.ParentItem.GetParentDataKeyValue("ReportsTo").ToString()
```

Per [Telerik's documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treelist-updating-inplace-editforms.html), if you are using **InPlace** edit mode you should cast the `TreeListEditableItem` to a `TreeListDataItem`; if you are using **EditForms** you should cast the `TreeListEditableItem` to a `TreeListEditFormItem`.

In order for GetDataKeyValue and GetParentDataKeyValue to return the values you want, you must set them in the respective DataKeyNames and ParentDataKeyNames values when defining a RadTreeList:

```
<telerik:RadTreeList ID="EmployeeTreeList" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" 
    ParentDataKeyNames="ReportsTo">
    <Columns>
        <%-- Add column definitions here --%>
    </Columns>
</telerik:RadTreeList>
```

Comment: I saw an example using TreeListEditableItem so I got stuck on that and didn't realize there was another type I could cast it as.  Thanks!!!